# invalid operands of types ‘int*’ and ‘long unsigned int’ to binary ‘operator*’ error in C

Tags: c

So I keep getting the following compilation error;

```
src/c/testHO.c: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
src/c/testHO.c:79:56: error: invalid operands of types ‘int*’ and ‘long unsigned int’ to       binary ‘operator*’
src/c/testHO.c:145:26: error: cannot convert ‘int*’ to ‘float*’ for argument ‘27’ to ‘void       hfmmcalc_(float*, float*, float*, float*, int*, int*, float*, float*, int*, double*, int*, int*, float*, float*, float*, float*, int*, int*, float*, float*, int*, int*, float*, int*, int*, float*, float*, float*, int*, int*)’
```

This error relates to the following part of the code

```
    int wkspSize = 32*(npart+NGRID)+1000;
    float* WKSP = (float*) malloc(wkspSize*sizeof(float));
    int hfmmInfoSize = 4;
    int* hfmmInfo = (int*) malloc(&hfmmInfoSize*sizeof(int));
```

I am struggling to find where this error is exactly. I have tried changing the both the 27th argument (hffmInfoSize) so that it is given as float and I have tried changing the final line as a float. I am fairly new to C so its probably a simple fix

Comment: The problems above are not related to the code you posted. There is a call to some "hfmmcalc_" with at least 27 arguments, the 27th of which should be a `float*` but you're passing an `int*`. The first error mentions "binary operator*"; for me this suggests you're compiling it as C++, not as C (I understand this error is gone since the corrections applied on the answer given by Paul R).

Comment: Perhaps, given the huge amount of arguments, you forgot something (or added some stray argument that should not be there). If this function is yours I suggest: either you break it up in pieces (surely the arguments are needed in chunks of code) OR create a struct to hold them all (or most of them), specially if the same list (or sublist) of arguments appear in the signature of many functions.

Answer (score 6):

You have a stray `&` in there it seems - change:

```
int* hfmmInfo = (int*) malloc(&hfmmInfoSize*sizeof(int));
```

to:

```
int* hfmmInfo = malloc(hfmmInfoSize*sizeof(int));
```

Note also the removal of the [redundant (and potentially dangerous) cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) on the result of the call to `malloc`.

Comment: I continue to get an error in argument 27 but this time; invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘int*’ [-fpermissive]

Comment: It seems that you have more than one problem - there is only enough information in your question to fix the problem I addressed above. You'll need to provide more info, specifically the prototype for `hfmmcalc_`, to get help with any further issues (preferably in a new question - StackOverflow has a "one question per question" policy).

Comment: Also make sure that you really are compiling this as C code, e.g. your source file should have a `.c` suffix, not a `.cpp` suffix.